The quality and size of the frame are the same, but the weight is different
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i /144.mp4 \
       -r 25 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast -profile:v main \
       -keyint_min 250 -g 250 -sc_threshold 0 \
       -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 \
        -map v:0 -filter:v:0 "scale=-2:144"  -b:v:0 448k  -maxrate:0 420k  -bufsize:0 588k \
       -map 0:a \
       -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
       -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
       -dash_segment_type mp4 \
       -use_template 1 \
       -use_timeline 0 \
       -seg_duration 10 \
       -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
       -f dash \
       /s/dash.mpd

**Source:** 144.mp4, frame 300x144, weight 10MB
**Output**: dash.mpd(folder weight '/s/'), frame 300x144, weight 30MB

What's wrong with the bitrate '-b:v:0 448k'?
Why is there such a discrepancy in the weight of files?
How to specify parameters:
-b:v:0 448k  -maxrate:0 420k  -bufsize:0 588k

So in case the source has a higher bitrate. At the output, limit it to the maximum. And in case the bitrate of the source is lower, leave it as it is. Do not result in what is specified in the parameters. How to do this?
ffprobe /144.mp4
ffprobe version N-100470-g5b48d2a Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs=-lpthread --extra-libs=-lm --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-libwebp --enable-pic --enable-ffplay --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libass --enable-libfribidi --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl --enable-libx265 --enable-libwebp
  libavutil      56. 62.100 / 56. 62.100
  libavcodec     58.115.102 / 58.115.102
  libavformat    58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 94.100 /  7. 94.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/144.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:08:18.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 174 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 256x144 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 37 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
    Stream #0:1(rus): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why is there such a difference in weight between the input file and the result (from 10 MB to 30 MB). The frame size is the same.

How to set the maximum bitrate (-b:v) for a file. If it is higher on the input file, then we limit it. If it’s less, we don’t do anything with it.

It's difficult for me to write in English. Sorry, google translate

The bitrate paramater is -b:v 450k, but the output size, although affected by bitrate, can be a lot of different reasons.  What does ffprobe 144.mp4 say?

bitrate: 174 kb/s, If I understand correctly. The output is '-b:v:0 448k'. Is it possible to ignore this parameter if the input bitrate is lower?

Yes, you can omit it completely.

Have you tried direct stream -c copy?
ffmpeg -re -f mpegts -hide_banner -y -i /144.mp4 -c copy -map v:0 -vf scale=144:-1 -map 0:a \
    -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
    -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
    -dash_segment_type mp4 \
    -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -seg_duration 10 \
    -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
    -f dash /s/dash.mpd

If that doesn't work, this is what matches the ffprobe stats:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i /144.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 174k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -map v:0 -map 0:a -s 256x144 -preset ultrafast \
    -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
    -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
    -dash_segment_type mp4 \
    -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -seg_duration 10 \
    -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
    -f dash /s/dash.mpd


If you have a whole bunch of segments, put them on a .m3u then use the playlist file for the input source: ffmpeg -i playlist.m3u...
M3U example:
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10.00,
segment_144_1_av.mp4

// List of files go here.

#EXTINF:10.0,
segment_144_100_av.mp4
#EXT-X-ENDLIST 


I'm not very experienced with multiple outputs, but this is the format:
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex '[0:v]yadif,split=3[out1][out2][out3]' \
        -map '[out1]' -s 1280x720 -c:v … -c:a … output1 \
        -map '[out2]' -s 640x480  -c:v … -c:a … output2 \
        -map '[out3]' -s 320x240  -c:v … -c:a … output3


Copying will not work. There are many files, each file has its own bitrate. You can first get the bitrate of the file and compare, then perform convection. But I think that ffmpeg provides a way out for such cases.

If the input file has poor quality. This cannot be fixed by increasing the bitrate. It will only increase the file weight, which is not good.

@Dmitrii The quality is low from the source, it seems.  It's only 144p.  I corrected the video filter in the first command and added -re.  Give that a try.

Can you please correct this using my example? I convect into 5 different qualities at once. In the example there is only one. If I try to integrate filters into my example. I'm afraid I'll sit on this for a very long time. Thank you
